# Why is the word "how" considered an adverb, even if the answer is an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, questions, parts-of-speech

Consider this question and its related answer:

> #### Question:
>
> **How** was the pizza?
>
> #### Answer:
>
> It was **delicious**.

The question is asking *how*, which is defined in every dictionary as an adverb, but the answer is *delicious*, which is an adjective.

Why is *how* considered an adverb, even in this case?

Comment: 'Why is "how" an adverb?' is impossible to answer, nor does it have any connection at all to with the adjective 'delicious'.

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford English Dictionary has a very long page of meanings for **how** (two senses are quoted below). 
Probably what you need is a better quality dictionary/grammar book!

The "adverb meaning"

> I.1.a. Qualifying a verb: In what way or manner? By what means?

The "adjective" meaning.

> I.2.a. In what condition or state? how are you?: (in quot. 1918) used ironically in sense ‘indeed!’ how do you do? (formerly how do you?):
>   common phrases used in inquiring as to a person's health. See also
>   how-do-ye phr. and n., how-do-you-do phr. and n.   Also, how goes it?
>   = how-do-you-do phr. and n. 1; how's (or how are) things (or, orig. Austral. and N.Z., tricks?) ; how do?: = how-do-you-do phr. and n.

Comment: Or you could say adverbs can (sometimes) be used adjectivally with the copula to be, just as other phrases can that are normally adverbial, or at least ones that normally cannot come before a noun: *I am good, I am well, I am in the cupboard.* The requirements for a subject complement after a copula are not as strictly adjectival as before a noun.

Comment: @Cerberus good point.

Comment: @tchrist I agree that *good* and *well* are too irregular to be of very much use. but at least there will be acknowledged some differences between prenominal and predicating adjectives. e.g., *The kindly old man/(x)The old man is kindly.* What is relevant here is that you can question a predicating adjective with *how*, but you need to use some elaborate formulation like *which kind of...* to question a prenominal adjective.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries generally label "how" as an adverb, though one gets into difficulties when one wants to show that it is an adverb. Adverbs modify several other word classes as verbs, adjectives, adverbs, even sentences. The only case where "how"  is used as modifier I can think of is "How funny". When you look at articles about kind of adverbs you find adverbs of manner/place/time/frequency/degree/ intensifiers/focus/viewpoints/connectives; so in Longman English Grammar. But you don't find an adverb class where "how" might belong to.

But modifying another word is not the main use of "how". It is mainly used to form questions and it is appropriate to label this use simply as question words, even though such a word class is normally not listed among the traditional word classes.

By the way, answers to how-questions can be of several types.  When you are asked "How do you go to your office?" you won't answer with an adjective.

Comment: It’s been said that branding something an adverb is an admission of failure to classify. :)

Answer (score 1):

How was the pizza? It was delicious.

The sentence "how was the pizza?" is what is called a surface, or S, structure. The semantics of the sentence would suggest that you were asking about the verb 'taste', e.g., "how does the pizza taste?", the answer to which the word 'how' seeks to elicit. There is a class of verbs like 'was' or 'taste' that take adjectives (like delicious) as complements, but still need a wh- question word (like how) when asking a question.

In standard syntax, wh- words are classified as syntactic adverbs just because they occur in the vicinity of the verb, a VP (verb phrase) constituent, to use the jargon.

Comment: Hello, Lolu. Aren't surface structures / deep structures posited in only certain forms of grammar?

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** It does not matter what part of speech which you or anybody else calls *how*; it only matters what it does.  *How* is a *wh*-question word, which are in a category of their own. They can be called into service to fulfil many different gramatical roles. **Asking after the condition of a noun** demands some sort of noun modifier <sup><sub>(or actual substantive)</sub></sup> in response, which is typically an adjective — just like here.

---

The way to determine the part of speech played by any word in a phrase or sentence is **not** by looking it up in a dictionary, but rather by examining the job which that word is doing in the actual sample being scrutinized.

So for example, we have all these different uses of *how*:

1. I don’t care about the **hows** or the whys; I just care about the results.
2. **How** so sir, did she change her determination? 
   (Shakespeare, 1592, *Merry Wives of Windsor*; ɪɪɪ. v. 69)
3. And so drew Argo up, with hale and **how**, On the grass.
    (William Morris, 1867, *Jason and the Argonauts*, x. 587)
4. I couldn’t figure out **how** to open the contraption for the life of me.
5. Bob Cratchit told them **how** he had a situation in his eye for Master Peter.
    (Charles Dickens, 1884, *A Christmas Carol*, iii)
6. Do you know any good **how**-to books on crochet?
7. Coming upon the Lone Ranger with his back turned, Tonto startled him with the traditional Sioux greeting, “**How**, Kemosabe.”
8. What need ye hech and **how**, ladies? What need ye **how** for me? 
   (Mary Hamilton, 1889, in Child *Ballads*)
9. To the top of Great **How** did it please them to climb.
    (William Wordsworth, 1800, *Rural Architecture*, 4)
10. Her acceptance of your apology depends on **how** you present it.
11. **How** silly!
12. **How** the hell did you ever do that?
13. **How** about a picnic in the park today?
14. **How** did the story turn out?
15. **How** many sugar packets would you like?
16. I put my whole back into it, and **how**!
17. **How** now, Malvolio?
     (Shakespeare, 1601, *Twelfth Night*, ɪɪɪ. iv. 16)
18. ‘Will you join us in a little conspiracy?’ 
    ‘**How** do you mean conspiracy, young man?’ 
    (Thackeray, 1849, *Pendennis*, lxxiv)
19. **How** is little Johnny coming along in his studies?
20. **How** does that that song go?
21. **How** do you feel?
22. **How** are those tomatoes?
23. **How** was show last night?

<sup><sub>(Several examples omitted for brevity.)</sub></sup>

As you see above, even when used as a *wh*-question word at the start of a question, *how* can fulfil many different roles.

When an interrogative sentence of the inverted form **Wh-V-S?** gets flipped around into normal word order and the *wh*-word replaced by something discrete, so **S-V-*X***, that *X* is **not** always an adverb or adverbial phrase.  It can be an adjective:

1. I feel **strong and healthy**.
2. These tomatoes are **tasty**.
3. Last night’s show was **boring**.

When that happens, it is because the original *how* was **not** asking an adverbial question like “by what means”.

Rather, it was asking about **the condition or state** of the subject. That’s why those answers are all adjectives: the verbs are copulae and so the predicate complement is adjectival **not** adverbial.

If this makes you classify *how* as an “adjective” here, then so be it.   It does not matter.

You really should **not** get so hung up on parts of speech, particularly those from that or this dictionary.  They are nothing but arbitrary assignments that vary widely according to the purpose of whoever is making them.  They serve little real purpose — and here, I believe, none at all.

It does not matter what you or anybody else calls ***how***; it only matters what it does.

Answer (score -3):

Adverbs are words which help describe an action. They themselves are a hybrid word class of adjective and verb hence adverb. "How quaint!" describes an ongoing action "to be" or "being" and also describes how you are being. I hope that helps.

Answer (score -4):

Where is the adjective?

If the question is about "was" (so,  adverb, as you noted), so is the answer.

Comment: The adjective is 'delicious'.

Comment: @Roaring We are talking about ***How,*** not *delicious.* :) Save your votes.

Comment: As I understand it, we are talking about why 'how' is an adverb when the answer is an adjective.

Comment: *Be* is a copular verb: its predicate complement is therefore always either nominal or adjectival, never adverbial.

Comment: @tchrist Superb! You're the only one to see what's going on here. Nevermind we don't agree on the ultimate answer. (I'm unable to upvote comments, among many other things, from my phone for now.)

Comment: @tchrist see also related comment by Cerberus. We are getting close.

Comment: @Roaring My answer may be short, but it was not posted in a haste.